# how to transmit true value to formal parameter in decorator function(pyqtSlot())?

Tags: pyqt5

first, see code below:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import (Qt, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLCDNumber, QSlider,
    QVBoxLayout, QApplication)


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def printLabel(self, str):
        print(str)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_sld_valueChanged(self, value):
        self.lcd.display(value)
        self.printLabel(value)

    def initUI(self):

        self.lcd = QLCDNumber(self)
        self.sld = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.lcd)
        vbox.addWidget(self.sld)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.sld.valueChanged.connect(self.on_sld_valueChanged)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Signal & slot')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm a little puzzled about how the true value in sld is transmitted to the formal parameter 'value' in the slot function : def sld_valChanged(self, value).

Because i can't see something like this: self.sld.valueChanged.connect(partial(self.sld_valChanged, self.sld.value))

Could someone explain that?

Comment: When the value of the slider is changed, a signal `valueChanged` is emitted by the slider by calling `QSlider.valueChanged.emit(value)` where `value` is the new value of the slider. All slots connected to this signal are then called automatically with `value` as their input argument.

Comment: But if I modify the code as below: add-> from PyQt5.QtCore import QMetaObject, replace self.sld.valueChanged.connect(self.on_sld_valueChanged) with QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(self) , the value will not change. Why this happen?